# Refresh <DIV> after submit data Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I want to show the total direct sales without reloading with angular js,

when I was still using the reload when processing cart

**JS**

```
    .controller('CartCtrl',function($scope,$http,$ionicPopup,$timeout,$location){

        $scope.plusCart = function() {
            $http({
                method  : 'POST',
                url     : 'http://192.168.1.33/so-ku/www/server/menu/plus_cart',
                headers : { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' },
                data    : JSON.stringify({ rowid: $scope.currentItem.rowid, qty : $scope.currentItem.qty })
            }).success(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                total_cart();
                location.reload(true);
            });
        }
  function total_cart() {
        $http.get('http://192.168.1.33/so-ku/www/server/menu/total_cart').
        then(function(response){
            $scope.total = response.data.records;
        });
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="CartCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="x in total" style="padding-top: 10px;" ng-init="total_cart()">
Rp {{x.total}}
</div>
</div>
```

I want result div with total is automatically calculated when i submit post

Comment: can you tell what exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Rp `{{total}}` is possibly what you want

Comment: I want result div with total is automatically calculated when i submit post

Answer (score 0):

If your `total_cart()` function works, then just remove the line with `location.reload(true)` and it should refresh the data.

Comment: total_cart is works when i reload data bro , i want to div element is automatically change value

Comment: Then just update `$scope.total` in your `.success` function based on the data you get from the server - we don't know what kind of data you're sending/receiving, so that's all the help we can give you without more information

Comment: cannot update div element automatically bro , this page must reload if you want show total automatic

Comment: Okay. So I'm not completely clear on what you're asking. I understood that when your `plusCart` function is called - e.g. the user adds an item into the cart - you want the shopping cart to update automatically without a page reload, right? Then you need to update the `$scope.total` variable based on what you pushed to the cart, and as a result, the `div` element representing the shopping cart will automatically update. That's really all there is to it.

Comment: The shopping card contents are bound to the `$scope.total` variable, right? So you have to add the new contents there ( like `$scope.contents.push($scope.currentItem)` or whatever ), and then the div will update automatically.

Comment: i try with it , but push not working bro 

function g_total_cart() {
        // $scope.tot = [];
        $http.get('http://localhost/so-ku/www/server/menu/total_cart').success(function(data) {
            $scope.tot = data.records;
                $scope.xtotal.push($scope.tot.total);
        });
    }

Answer (score 0):

To chain two $http operations, first be sure the subsequent function returns the promise from the $http call:

```
function total_cart_promise() {
    var url = 'http://192.168.1.33/so-ku/www/server/menu/total_cart';
    //save promise
    var promise = $http.get(url)
      .then(function(response){
        $scope.total = response.data.records;
    });
    //return promise for chaining
    return promise;
};
```

Then in the first function, use the `.then` method and **return** the subsequent promise to the first XHR success handler:

```
$scope.plusCart = function() {
    $http({
        method  : 'POST',
        url     : 'http://192.168.1.33/so-ku/www/server/menu/plus_cart',
        //headers : { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' },
        //data    : JSON.stringify({ rowid: $scope.currentItem.rowid, qty : $scope.currentItem.qty })
        data    : { rowid: $scope.currentItem.rowid, 
                    qty : $scope.currentItem.qty }
    //}).success(function(data) {
    //USE .then method
    }).then(function successHandler(response) {
        console.log(response.data);
        //total_cart();
        //return promise to chain subsequent XHR
        return total_cart_promise();
        //location.reload(true);
    });
}
```

By chaining to subsequent XHR GET methods, there is no need to reload the page.

*Because calling the `.then` method of a promise returns a new derived promise, it is easily possible to create a chain of promises. It is possible to create chains of any length and since a promise can be resolved with another promise (which will defer its resolution further), it is possible to pause/defer resolution of the promises at any point in the chain. This makes it possible to implement powerful APIs.* --[AngularJS $q Service API Reference - Chaining Promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises)

Also note that there is no need to stringify the data, the AngularJS framework uses `Content-Type: application/json` by default and the framework automatically does `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: @AzizalYunanP In that case there are other XHRs that need to be added to the chain. Also `ng-init="total_cart()"` is sketchy. `ng-init` should not be used to initiate XHRs. Please edit the question to provide a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).